# Substitute the second occurrence of a date string

Tags: regex, perl

The *second* occurrence of a date in round brackets, likie `(6.12.2016)`, should be replaced with empty round brackets `()`

I tried the following:

```
my $dateoccurence = 2;

$content =~ s/(\(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\))/ --$dateoccurence == 0 ? "()" : $1 /ge;
```

Comment: I don't believe this question deserves what are presumably *it's obvious* downvotes. I admit that it seems likely that this isn't the OP's code because it uses the *expression* (`/e`) modifier intelligently, which doesn't square with missing the point that `6` isn't matched by `\d{2}`, but we all overlook the obvious from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The digits are not always two, there can be only one:

```
/(\(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}\))/
```

or, shorter

```
/(\(\d\d?\.\d\d?\.\d{4}\))/
```